# Assigning a UCC Cert to multiple domains that all reside on a single Dedicated Server via IIS?

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

So here's the scenario: I bought a UCC through GoDaddy. We host multiple web applications on a dedicated server which I access via RDP. UCC is meant to give you the ability to assign the same cert to multiple domains (GoDaddy told us 10). I added the domains to the UCC via GoDaddy's dashboard, then downloaded and installed the cert on the server.

[Defining the Domains on GoDaddy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY0Xe.png)

However, when attempting to assign the cert to each web app in IIS, a few things happen. 1) It warns me when I try to assign the cert to more than 1 application, 2) The "Host Name" field is greyed out when editing the site bindings, and 3) Once I assign the cert to the 2nd website, all traffic starts redirecting to the website I first assigned the cert to.

[Here you see the Host Name Grey Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Wuj.png)

Does anyone know how to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Hints https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are applying a non-wildcard certificate in IIS 7.5 or lower version. IIS will gray out host name field if you are applying a certificate without wildcard common name.

To fix this, Please apply a valid certificate with wildcard common name or upgrade your Operating system.

Or you could try this with command line

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/asiatech/setting-up-a-wildcard-certificate-in-iis-7-how-to-avoid-those-certificate-mismatch-errors